# jQuery: running a function on load, and on an event - .keyup() and .each()

Tags: jquery, coding-style, dry

I have a question concerning style/compactness.  I have a function which I want to run once when my document loads, and also whenever an event is triggered.

My code looks something like this:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){my_function(etc);});
$('.myClass').keyup(function(){my_function(etc);});
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to combine these two lines of code into one.  It works fine at present, but the fact that I'm repeating code has me thinking that there could be a more succinct way to do this.

.bind() and .on() gave me no joy.  I am assuming this is because they're intended for events, and .each() isn't an event.

Can anybody offer any insight?  Cheers

Comment: You are not repeating code. You are calling the already separated out code from different sources. Where is the repeated code?

Comment: I guess you want to trigger `keyup` event as part of page initialization?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl 'my_function(etc);' is the bit I want to avoid repeating if possible.

Thanks to everyone who has offered insight.  It doesn't look like I can avoid repeating that bit but I appreciate your time regardless, and at least I can save an extra line :)  Thanks again.

Comment: @nrodic thank you, I revisited my question and realised your trigger suggestion was what I wanted, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ is iterator

The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is a map (JavaScript object) or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.

`keyup` is event: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Hope it fits the cause and lemme know if I missed anything! `:)`

Try this:

```
$(".myClass").each(my_function(etc))
             .bind("keyup mouseover", my_function(etc));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose javascript code in function block:

```
(function($){
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

and use local variables then you won't mess with global namespace (window).

**Then** inside that function block you can declare and use function like

```
function my_named_function(etc){};
$('.myClass').each(my_named_function)
    .keyup(my_named_function);
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
my_function=function(){
//do something  
}  
$('.myClass').each(my_function)
             .keyup(my_function);
```